# Add new geofence(s) every time the sever pushes

Tags: android, geofencing

Initially, I have added 5 geofences to LocationClient.

After some time I need to add new geofences, say 3.

What shall I do to have all 8 geofences active.

Shall I remove initial 5 geofences and add all 8 at once. OR
Shall I add 3 new geofences as below.

```
Intent geofenceIntent = new Intent(this, GeofenceIntentService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                                                 0,
                                                 geofenceIntent,
                                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
locationClient.addGeofences(geofences, pIntent, LocationIntentService.this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a database storing all geofence info. When adding a new geofence, you can first record it into the database. And then retrieve all geofences in the databse, and add them all to the locationClient as new geofences.

Comment: Yes I have a database. Shall I remove previous geofences before adding all again?

Why would we actually need to give as a set of geofences instead adding one by one as per our needs.

Comment: No need to remove the previous geofences. Remove geofence only when you no longer need it. Sorry that I cannot find relevant documents, but I had wrote a geofence app before, and what I answered is from my experience. When I tried to add geofence one by one, I remember that only the lastest one got registered. The previous ones won't work. And adding all will somehow replace the old ones. Also, I started with downloading the template here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html